# How to set the OAuth authorization token in a typescript-jquery client generated from Swagger

Tags: jquery, typescript, swagger

I've generated the bindings for a swagger defined API that requires an OAuth token.

```
swagger-codegen generate -i api.json -o test -l typescript-jquery
```

But it looks to me that the headers are hardcoded in the generated code.

Is there a way to set the authorization header without modifying the generated code?

Comment: Does your api.json file contain `securityDefinitions`+`security` keywords for OAuth? How does the generated code look like, and how would you expect it to look like? What version of swagger-codegen do you use?

Comment: Hi, let's assume yes, l have no idea, and latest stable. Do you have an example on how to call it using oauth, and using the result in a .then?

Comment: For a newby the landscape of typescript clients for swagger looks a minefield full of half-assed libraries and almost no-example. A good tutorial on how to use the client would probably do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way, or the recommended one but I worked around the apparent api limitations setting the headers in jquery before calling the generated SDK.

```
jquery.ajaxSettings.headers = { ... }
```

It looks that when the `securityDefinitions` are provided, as noted in a comment the generator will take into consideration the token in the configuration: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/2.3.0_BACKUP_ONLY/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/typescript-jquery/api.mustache#L174

Part of the problem is that it was not possible to use the typescript-jquery bindings at all, the generated code looks like:

```
    let dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax(requestOptions).then(
        (data: models.Operation, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) =>
            dfd.resolve(jqXHR, data),
        (xhr: JQueryXHR, textStatus: string, errorThrown: string) =>
            dfd.reject(xhr, errorThrown)
    );
    return dfd.promise();
```

While my new-to-the-topic opinion is that it should look more like:

```
    let dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax(requestOptions).then(
        (data: models.Operation, textStatus: string, jqXHR: JQueryXHR) =>
            dfd.resolve({ request: jqXHR, body: data }),
        (xhr: JQueryXHR, textStatus: string, errorThrown: string) =>
            dfd.reject({ request: xhr, body: errorThrown})
    );
    return dfd.promise();
```

Given that the signature of the generated method is:

```
public someMethod(): JQueryPromise<{ response: JQueryXHR; body: models.Operation;  }>
```

Not sure about the `reject` part, but both the compiler and intellisense are happier.